# Python, matplotlib pyplot show() not blocking

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having trouble with the `show()` function not blocking. I've taken over a python application from someone that left and I seem to remembering this worked on his (IT reclaimed) PC.
Here's the code ...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.title("Molding X Error")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("X Error")
plt.plot( ... details that work and not the problem ... )
plt.show(block=True)
        
plt.title("Molding Y Error")
plt.xlabel("Y")
plt.ylabel("Y Error")        
plt.plot( ... details that work and not the problem ... )
plt.show(block=True)
```

On the other guys PC, the first `show()` would display appropriately.
After dismissing the first, the second would display.

I run it, and it not only doesn't stop on the first `show()`, it combines data from both the first and second with the title and labels from the second.

I step through with the debugger, and the first does show, but stepping to the second the same result is seen.

Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.
Python2.7.10, Anaconda 2.3.0 which contains (apparently) matplotlib1.4.3

Note: I did read through "(python) matplotlib pyplot show() .. blocking or not?" where it was from 2011 and was referring to matplotlib1.0.1 as a solution.

Comment: Update: I changed the code to include plt.figure(1) and plt.figure(2) before each plt.title("...") call and both get displayed separately but both immediately.   This is not blocking, but it is a probably going to be acceptable for this 2 graph situation.  There is another with 14 graphs so a solution to why this didn't block would still be appreciated.

Comment: `plt.show` should block by default. Is your example the whole code? Look for something like `plt.ion()`.

Comment: This is not all the code.  The application contains multiple files and classes,  ... not a ton, but quite a bit of code.  Anyway, I did a search through all the code for "ion" and it is not in the code anywhere.   A small extra note, the "block=True" in the plt.show() call, ... I added after I saw it in another posting somewhere ... it had no affect on the issue.

Comment: How do you run the code? Are you maybe using Ipython? Or are you having matplotlibrc with the option `interactive: true`? What happens if you call `plt.rcdefaults()` at the very beginning of your script?

Comment: I am using "JetBrains PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.4" IDE and have been running from it.  After reading your question, I tried running from the command line "python Model_GUI.py" with the same result.

Comment: Also, I did try the plt.rcdefaults() first (I thought that sounded encouraging) but that did not make the Show() block on each encounter.

Comment: Have you checked for a `matplotlibrc` file in the directory you are running the code and in your home folder? Here are the paths: http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html.

Answer (score 0):

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=plot#matplotlib.pyplot.show

> In non-interactive mode, display all figures and block until the figures have been closed; in interactive mode it has no effect unless figures were created prior to a change from non-interactive to interactive mode (not recommended). In that case it displays the figures but does not block.
>   A single experimental keyword argument, block, may be set to True or False to override the blocking behavior described above.

Comment: virgula24, I did see this ... "block until the figures have been closed" ... is what was expected and desired.   (Also, as I said at the top of the post, was working on the previous persons' PC.)   I'm thinking it may be some sort of environment setting, python package installation thing?

Comment: im not a python expert but maybe dig into the source code of matlib for that particular function or just reimage that persons pc

Comment: I have tried to get more documentation on these matplotlib.pyplot functions. I found manual pages but the information is very terse.

Comment: best option is to reimage that computer. or have fun digging in the source code. maybe create a issue and let them help you https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/0037595096e3be3ec863f3e3008e73c469e2f2b8/lib/matplotlib